# ls: use different color for "user" and "group" columns, when file owned by root

Tags: zsh, ls, colors

When using `ls -lAhF`, the 3rd and 4th columns are user and group ownership, ie:

```
drwxrwxrwt 2 root  root   60 Nov 15 15:50 .X11-unix/
srwxr-xr-x 1 marti marti   0 Nov 15 15:51 .menu-cached-:0-marti=
srwxr-xr-x 1 marti marti   0 Nov 15 15:51 .pcmanfm-socket--0-marti=
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root   80 Nov 15 15:50 dtach/
drwx------ 2 marti marti  40 Nov 16 17:36 mc-marti/
drwx------ 2 root  root   40 Nov 16 20:25 mc-root/
```

I would like to have the keyword "root" in 3rd and 4th columns colored red, so that I can easily see that file is owned by root.

So, if user group are other than root, everything looks as before

If user is root, the keyword "root" in the 3rd  column is color red. Similarly for group root.

How could I do that ?
**I am using 'zsh' as my shell.**

I don't think `ls` has the possibility to configure that. But could I use some alias / function in `zsh` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will colour `root` in red wherever it appears in `ls`’s output followed by a space:

```sh
ls() {
    if [ -t 1 ]; then
        command ls --color=always "$@"| sed "s/root /$(tput setaf 1)root$(tput sgr0) /g"
    else
        command ls "$@"
    fi
}
```

This will match `root` in the user and group columns, but also in files containing “`root`” (with a space) so it might not be exactly what you want. Forcing colour output will at least ensure that it doesn’t match files named “root”.

The `sed` invocation can use Zsh-specific features instead of `tput`:

- `echoti`: `sed "s/root /$(echoti setaf 1)root$(echoti sgr0) /g"`
- [prompt expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion): `sed "s/root /${(%):-%F{red}root${(%):-%f} /g"` (yes, the first brace is unbalanced)
- `colors` (`autoload colors; colors`): `sed "s/root /${fg[red]}root${reset_color} /g"`

If your terminal supports more than 16 colours, you can use larger values with `setaf`. `%F{red}` can also use numeric values. [The `nearcolor` module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fnearcolor-Module) gives an easy way to find the closest matching colour to a desired RGB value.

If you have an existing `ls` *alias*, setting `--color=tty`, you’ll need to disable it, otherwise `--color=tty` will come after `--color=always` in the `ls` invocation and `ls`’s own colouring will be disabled.

Comment: In `zsh`, you could replace `$(tput setaf 1)` with `$(echoti setaf 1)` (where `echoti` is builtin in the zsh/terminfo module) or `${(%):-%F{red}}` or after `autoload colors; colors`, `$fg[red]`

Comment: sgr0 would be `${(%):-%f}`, `$reset_color`

Comment: @Stephen Kitt - How can I use a color from the 256-color palette ? For instance the red "202" ?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - can I use colors from  the 256-color palette ? How can I use the red "202" instead of `setaf 1` ?

Comment: @MartinVegter, well `echoti setaf 202` or `%F{202}` assuming your `$TERM` refers to the right terminfo entry. See also the RGB `%F{#FF2200}` which also works with terminals that don't have RGB escape sequences provided you load the `zsh/nearcolor` module.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt - what is the advantage of using this approach, rather than the `grep` solution suggested by @bxm. The grep solution looks much simpler. Are there situations where your solutions would work better than @bxm's ?

Comment: This approach allows you to choose the exact colour you want.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
function ls {
  command ls "$@" | grep -E --color=always "^|root "
}
```

For the sake of simplicity this will colour the word `root` in any file names too.

I’ve not added a check for pipeline usage, but you can see such in the other answers here.

Comment: actually, it does not color the word "root" in filenames. Any downside in using your approach, as compared to the sed solution above ?

Comment: May not be as portable — not all `grep` support the `--color`